# Semistable sheaves on a K3 which are not simple

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Does anybody know any example of a semistable and nonsimple sheaf on a K3 surface $S$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trival sheaf $\mathcal O_S\oplus\mathcal O_S$ is one: it has non-trivial global endomorphism algebra $gl_2(k)$ and is semi-stable.

Comment: Are you sure it is semi-stable?

Comment: Every line bundle is semistable, and a direct sum of semistable sheaves with the same slope is semistable with that slope.